# set default textarea size in user controls which doesn't not reduce incase multiple textareas are used

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, .net

the below code is of the text area,this is inside user controls

```
<textarea id="txtPrecautionStatement" runat="server" enableviewstate="false"
            class="form-control-lg col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-lg-6 col-xl-5 bottom-gap font-small"
            onkeydown="return checkTextAreaMaxLength(this,event,'500');" onblur="limitnofotext(this,500)" onkeypress="AutoGrowTextArea()"
            style="height: 40px;" rows="1" cols="1"></textarea>
```

now jquery code that auto resizes the textareas

```
function AutoGrowTextArea() {
    jQuery('textarea').each(function () {
        this.setAttribute('style', 'height:' + (this.scrollHeight) + 'px;overflow-y:hidden;');
    }).on('input', function () {
        //this.style.height = (this.scrollHeight) + 'px';
        var sh = this.scrollHeight;
        this.style.height = sh < 40 ? "40px" : sh + "px";
    });
}
```

but i have 2 textareas here. if i enter any value in first one, the second one starts shrinking

Comment: while loading the page, both textareas have 40px height. but as soon as i start entering in any one text area, the other shrinks in size as the current expands.

Comment: Where is the 2nd textarea (and I guess that's HTML server control too)? I tested in a fiddle & 2nd textarea (which I copied from first one) doesn't seem to shrink: https://jsfiddle.net/cdLdp8vh/. What's exactly going wrong?

Comment: yes i checked in your fiddle, it is not how i get, i have disabled the scrollbar, in your fiddle the jquery is not executing

Comment: thanks for your help, i managed to find out , needed to change the jquery a bit and it works perfectly.    -----------------------------------------------            function AutoGrowTextArea(id) {
    jQuery("#" + id).on('input', function () {
        this.setAttribute('style', 'height:' + (this.scrollHeight) + 'px;overflow-y:hidden;');
        this.style.height = 'auto';
        var sh = this.scrollHeight;
        this.style.height = sh < 40 ? "40px" : sh + "px";
    });
}